# strange behavior / problems with the positioning of a text in an SVG // IE problems

Tags: css, svg

I'm just about to position a text (a headline) in a SVG vertically AND, that **the IE also kept the peculiar width**. BUT in IE, this headline is made smaller and somehow funny. Well, now I've read about a **paddin-bottom-hack that I've used now**. Here is my source code:

```css
h1 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 3em;
    min-height: 5em;        
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-content:center;
    font-family: 'Variable-Bold';
    font-size: 1.6em; 
    line-height: 1; 
    letter-spacing:0;
    margin-right: 0.6em;
    max-width: 3.5em;
            border: 6px dotted yellow;
}
   .scaling-svg-container {
            position: relative; 

            width: 100%; 
            padding: 0;
            padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
h1 svg {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 13em;
             position: absolute; 
             height: 100%; 
             width: 100%; 
            left: 0; 
            top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="scaling-svg-container" 
                            style="padding-bottom: 24.0385%">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 208" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path id="verticalPath" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M37.05,208 V0"/>
                <rect x=4 y=4 width=42 height=200 stroke-width="3" stroke="#ff6e00" fill="none"/>
                <text x="104.3" text-anchor="middle" fill="#ff6e00">
                    <textpath href="#verticalPath">Meine Überschrift</textpath>
                </text>
            </svg>
</h1>
```

In IE it currently looks like this:
[SCREEN IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9SUE.jpg)

The headline is displayed within the area with (orange) border from the middle (indicated here with a yellow line) towards the top! WHY DO THIS BELOW? Why is not the headline displayed from bottom to top? What is wrong here in the source code? And that is only in IE!

Second PROB)
In all other browsers, the orange-bordered headline is now no longer displayed (vertical) centered (in the up-front yellow, dotted area), the display flex; and flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-content: center; , all that does not work now, suppose that has the position: relative; / position: absolute; to do. With which option can I now in (two) directions (what just get content-content: center; align-content: center; get) this heading (center) position? How do you do that?

Oh yes: An example can be seen here [Visual link website](https://www.tassilosturm.de/index_test.html)

Can you help me please?

The misanthrop

Comment: Why use an svg, why not just rotate some text - you seem to be using the font anyway

Comment: All right, but what about fallback on older browsers and IE 10+. How would you do it?

Comment: all modern supported browsers can handle transforms - https://caniuse.com/#search=transform.  as for ie10 microsoft don't even support that anymore... (although transforms still work in it if you definitely want to have support for it)

Comment: Well, I do not know, does anyone know a solution to my problem? Who knows about svg's?